# Is onfling available for html, html5

Tags: javascript, html

Is onfling or onpan available for html, html5

Comment: You're asking whether there are "fling" and "pan" events available in web browsers?  If so the answer is "no", unless you generate them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. These are not part of HTML5.

I think they are Android specific.

A list of HTML5 events can be found here:

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp